# Tailwind CSS not working after build showing a warning

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

[this is the warning i am getting in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ4LC.png)i am using TailwindCSS in my react project...which i have build using parcel and babel...i have cross checked the `.postcssrc` file , `taiwind.config.js` file and tried to reinstall my TailwindCSS through the same procedures again and again...i cannot share the code as it is too long and contains multiple components ...THE JSX IS WORKING PROPERLY ..I.E. THE HTML IS GETTING RENDERED PROPERLY BUT CSS IS NOT GETTING ATTACHED..i have cross checked the `index.html` also its contains my CSS link tag. I have included all the utilities that are required to be added. AND YESTERDAY I GOT A WARNING IN MY CONSOLE after I BUILD MY APP THAT `No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the`content `option in your Tailwind CSS configuration`. Now it is not showing any warning of that kind, but still the CSS is not working. FOR YOUR INFORMATION IT WAS WORKING IN MY LAST PROJECT. IT IS NOT WORKING FOR MY THIS PROJECT

i have tried literally everything and now I want my Tailwind CSS to work properly

Comment: What did you set your `content` property inside of `tailwind.config.js` to? It should be something like `content: ['./src/**/*.jsx'],` depending on your project structure.

Comment: @decho i have attached an image also....you can see there...i have cross checked the `content` file its correct

Comment: Assuming that `tailwind.config.js` is in project root, and your jsx files are in `src` directory, then on paper your configuration looks correct. Have you checked the generated `.css` file(s), how do they look like? It's a bit hard to tell what's wrong with the limited information given here.

Comment: got the error ..there was problem in my folder structure